# How to delete a zip file using php

Tags: php, zip

This is my php code to delete a zip file:

```
$name = "zip_file_name";
chmod('./modules/',0777);
unlink('./modules/'.$name.'.zip');
```

Here `modules` is the folder of zip file contained. When I wrote this code I got an error:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">



<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>



<p>Severity: Warning</p>

<p>Message:  unlink(./modules/texts.zip) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: Permission denied</p>

<p>Filename: controllers/super_admin.php</p>

<p>Line Number: 590</p>



</div>
```

If there is any mistake in my code?

I also check the `chmod` like this:

```
chmod('./modules/'.$name.'.zip',0777);
```

But I got the same error define above.

Comment: What are the permissions of the actual file? you are only setting the ones for the directory..

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you would have to change permissions to the zip, to make it writable first

```
chmod('./modules/'.$name.'.zip',0666);
```

666 = read / write for all
Make sure that will return true. But since you cannot delete the file, most likely you will not be able to change it's permission also as Apache is not the owner.

777 for the parent directory is required only to write new files to that directory, do not affect operations that you can do with files that are already there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "zip_file_name";
$sPath = "./modules/" . $name . ".zip";
$aFilePath = explode("/", $sPath);
$i = 0;
$sLastFolder = "";
foreach ($aFilePath as $sFolder) {
    $i++;
    if (file_exists($sLastFolder . $sFolder) || is_dir($sLastFolder . $sFolder)) {
        $this->make_writeable($sLastFolder . $sFolder);
        $iOldumask = umask(0); // important part #1
        chmod($sLastFolder . $sFolder, 0777);
        umask($iOldumask); // important part #2
        $sLastFolder .= $sFolder . "/";
    }
}
unlink($sPath);
```