# Removing zipped folder By PHP Code

Tags: php, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a zip file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968324/how-to-delete-a-zip-file-using-php)

How can I remove zipped directory using php code?

I have a folder `test`. In that folder there have a  zipped directory name `zip_folder`.
I want to remove this zipped directory from test folder. How can I do this?

I wrote some code, but its not working. This is my code:

```
$name = "zip_folder";
chmod('./test/'.$name.'.zip',777);
unlink('./test/'.$name.'.zip');
```

I got an error like this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">



<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>



<p>Severity: Warning</p>

<p>Message:  unlink(./test/zip_folder.zip) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: Permission denied</p>

<p>Filename: controllers/super_admin.php</p>

<p>Line Number: 590</p>



</div>
```

What is the problem in my code?

In `zip_folder` have subfolders also. In `test` folder there have `zip_folder.zip` and `zip_folder` folder. That means there have zipped copy of `zip_folder` and an original folder of `zip_folder`. I need to remove only the zipped copy of `zip_folder`.

Comment: Don't get confused by terminology. A *.zip archive is, to all effects, just a file. Also, are you sure that `chmod()` works as expected? If you don't have permission to write a file, you can't normally assign it to yourself.

Comment: Please don't write the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below function for deleting folders and subfolders... You need to pass only folder path...

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                    if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
                }
            }
        reset($objects);
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nothing will happen i passed the folder path as `rrmdir('./test/'.$name.'.zip');`

Comment: You need to pass folder name. Not file name... I think you need to remove zip directory and its content files. So you need to specifically pass folder..

Answer (score 0):

The `chmod` is failing to change the mode. Check the result. See the Notes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for reasons why it can fail.